# Sci-fi book about a brain chip implanted in your head that would tell you anything your phone could and more

Tags: story-identification, audio-book, brain-implant

Around 5-7  years ago, I listened to an audio book about this new technology that came out where you could have a chip implanted in your head that would tell you anything your phone could and more. If you were to look at a person, it would tell you about their character.

There were other things, like a test site somewhere where they were experimenting on people's natural behavior to see if they could change them.

The last thing I remember is that the creator made the chip so that he could control people who had it, mainly by killing them, and there was a guy who was trying to stop him from killing a bunch of people in London.

Both the antagonist and protagonist were men, and in the end, the antagonist was trying to kill the protagonist by running him off the road or shutting down the chip in his driver's head.

Comment: How *many* years ago? Ten, twenty, forty?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the protagonist, such as their sex and approximate age?

Comment: Isn't this the plot of *Kingsman: The Secret Service*?

Comment: It was probably 5-7 years ago, both the antagonist and protagonist were men. In the end the antagonist was trying to kill the protagonist by running him off the road or shutting down the chip in his drivers head.

Comment: I found it! The Utopia Experiment is what it is called.

Comment: Todos Santos by Jerry Pournelle, 30 or 40 years old. Where all the top management of a large company has that kind of chip.

Answer (score 11):

[The Utopia Experiment](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/16032631) by Robert Ludlum:

> With U.S. intelligence agencies wracked by internal power struggles and paralyzed by bureaucracy, the president has been forced to establish his own clandestine group--Covert-One. It's activated only as a last resort, when the threat is on a global scale and time is running out.
>
> When Dresner Industries unveils the Merge, a device that is destined to revolutionize the world and make the personal computer and smartphone obsolete, Covert-One operative Colonel Jon Smith is assigned to assess its military potential. He discovers that enhanced vision, real-time battlefield displays, unbreakable security, and near-perfect marksmanship are only the beginning of a technology that will change the face of warfare forever--and one that must be kept out of the hands of America's enemies at all costs.
>
> Meanwhile, in the mountains of Afghanistan, CIA operative Randi Russell encounters an entire village of murdered Afghans--all equipped with enhanced Merge technology that even the Agency didn't know existed. As Smith and Russell delve into the circumstances surrounding the Afghans' deaths, they're quickly blocked by someone who seems to have access to the highest levels of the military--a person that even the president knows nothing about.
>
> Is the Merge really as secure as its creator claims? And what secrets about its development is the Pentagon so desperate to hide? Smith and Russell are determined to learn the truth. But they may pay for it with their lives.

Comment: Hey, it's great that you figured it out, but you could make this a better answer by including a short synopsis of the story.  And don't forget to come back in two days and accept this answer.